# If the union is measurable, so each set is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-sets

Let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ be a ordered pair, consisting of a arbitrary set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{X}$.

If $A \in \mathcal{X}$ and $A=A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$, with $A_i \in X$ and $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$, is possible state that each $A_i \in \mathcal{X}$?

In other words, if the finite union of pairwise disjoint sets is measurable then is each set measurable?

Comment: How about if $A_1$ is a non-measurable set and $A_2$ is its complement?

Comment: No. Take $A_1$ to be any non-measurable set, $A_2$ to be the complement of $A_1$, and $A_3$ to be empty.

Comment: (1) in the title, do you mean "then" instead of "so". (2) do you mean "with $A_i \subseteq X$" instead of "with $A_i \in X$". (3) of course it's possible that each $A_i \in \mathcal{X}$; e.g., $A_1 = A$ and $A_2,A_3 = \emptyset$. do you mean "must each $A_i \in \mathcal{X}$"? if so, then the answer is obviously "no", since you can have $A_1$ be non-measurable, $A_2 = A\setminus A_1$, and $A_3 = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. If you pick any two disjoint non-measurable $A_1,A_2$ sets in $[0,1]$ and set $A_3=([0,1] \backslash A_1) \backslash A_2$ you get a counterexample.

Comment: A much simpler and almost obvious example is in the comments.